# ImageMagick on multiple files

Tags: shell, wildcards, quoting, imagemagick

I have converted a single file from BMP to PNG with ImageMagick's `convert` using the command below

```
convert CD\ Front.bmp CD\ Front.png
```

I have many such files, thus I tried:

```
for f in */*.bmp ; do convert $f ${f%bmp}png; done
```

but this command hangs forever.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You most likely have a problem because you don't quote the file names:

```
for f in */*.bmp ; do convert "$f" "${f%bmp}png" ; done
#                             ^  ^ ^           ^
```

do this so the space in the file names do not cause problems.

Comment: `$f` should be quoted too

Comment: You are right, thank you for pointing out

Comment: Quoting the variables is correct, but if you quote the glob then the shell will look for a literal `*/*.bmp`.

Comment: Thanks to you as well. I should try out my solutions before posting...

Answer (score 18):

You can use mogrify:

```
mogrify -format png *.bmp
```

Source: [Imagemagick website](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor the code like this. I find this method to be clearer & easier to debug:

```
find . -type f -name '*.bmp' |\
  while read BMP
  do
    DIR=$(dirname "$BMP")
    PNG="$(echo $BMP | sed 's/.bmp//g')"
    convert "${BMP}" "${PNG}".png
  done
```

Comment: I took the liberty to change JPEG into PNG while reviewing

Comment: Ahh, thanks. But it did work for JPEG’s as well!

Comment: Yes, guess it does, but it was not what the OP asked for ;-)

Comment: Don't use `find | while read`, especially when a glob will suffice.

Comment: And the sed would be better as `'s/\.bmp$/.png/'`, then obviously remove the .png from the actual command